# How to get the count and list off all records according to a condition

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table in postgres 14:

```
user  team 
1      A
10     B
113    C
12     A
1      B
113    A
12     C
1      C
113    B
```

What is the best way to query the count of distinct `user` that is in all 3 teams `A, B, C` and the list of all these user

**The output should:**

```
count   list_user
2       [1, 113]
```

I am trying to use `cte's` for each one of the 3 teams but the query is running forever and is not retrieving any results then timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a double aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
       STRING_AGG(user::text, ',') AS list_user
FROM
(
    SELECT user
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE team IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT team) = 3
) t;
```

Comment: Biegelsein I have to cast `STRING_AGG(user::text, ',')...` because I got an error `ERROR: function string_agg(bigint, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`  Then it worked.  Huge thanks mna ;-)